# BigQuery table number grows limetless - how to stop it?

Tags: logging, google-bigquery

We've racked up logging information for 3 month and the amount of information is enormous, because all these tables have logging entries we would like to get rid of oldest entries as well as tables where them are stored.

We tried different approaches from either using `bq` command tool or issuing API rest services request. We've succeeded in it.

Now, the thing is: Is there a more suitable tool that eases management of log tables in BigQuery? I'm thinking in a tool like `logrotate` on Unix/Linux SO.

Comment: How did you organized your tables?

Comment: We divided logs entries based on their nature.  We have system log,  server log entries and mongodb  stored on ```syslog_local0_info_YYYYMMDD```, ```nodeserver_production_YYYYMMDD``` and ```mongodb_YYYYMMDD``` respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Tool" we are using is expiration set on dataset level. It works exactly as you would expect w/o any your further involvement.
Say you set 90 days.
Any new table "automaticaly" gets expiration set to 90 days since its creation.

See "defaultTableExpirationMs" in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response it was very useful. There is a hidden detail in the documentation, from my perspective it's a bit unclear.

For those who want to set up *defaultTableExpirationMs* you will need to specify expiration in seconds instead of milliseconds.  This value will be added to the table creation time.

I issued the command bellow and worked for me:

`bq update --default_table_expiration 5184000 -d your_project:data_set`

*NOTE:*  The tables remain two month long  (5184000 = 60 * 60 * 24 * 60).